# Gamblers ruin probability question

Tags: probability

I am playing blackjack and have a 52% chance to double my bet and a 48% to lose my bet. I have a finite bankroll and the casino has an infinite bankroll. I can not change the amount that I bet. Am I guaranteed to lose all of my money if I play an infinite amount of games?

Comment: You assume a game with an advantage for you. In this case, you have a chance to never drift to a negative result, so the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 0):

Guraranteed? No, not at all. Even with $1\%$ chance to win and $99\%$ chance to lose your bet you wouldn't be guaranteed to lose all your money.

If you, on the other hand, mean "Does the probability that I eventually lose all my money go to $1$ as I continue playing", then the answer to that is also no, although the math is a lot more complicated. Basically, this game has an advantage to you, so there is a strictly positive probability that you will never go broke.

Specifically, if we let $P_k$ be the probability of you reaching a fortune of $k$ without first going broke, when you start with enough money in your bankroll to make $N$ bets, then
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}P_k = 1-\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^N
$$